# recvmsg ip v4 fragment flag ancillary

Tags: sockets, ipv4

Looking into recvmg man page, could not find a way to get ip version 4 fragment flags. Is that possible?

If not, do you know any other ways other than raw_socket to get this for incomming UDP packets?

If there is non, I have a bad feeling about raw socket's read performance of a socket application. Because it is more like capturing all packets.

The event cycle of the application will be kept busy on receiving many waste packets instead of usfull socket data. Do you guys acknowledge that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to find out whether the packet was previously fragmented? Because by the time you receive it, all fragments will have been gathered.

Comment: No I just trying to find out if the packet was sent with the DF bit set or not.